# Topological dual of a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, isometry, dual-spaces

I am solving a problem from Rudin's Functional Analysis book, where I have to show that the topological dual of $\ell^p$, $0<p<1$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^{\infty}$. The metrics on $\ell^p$ and $\ell^{\infty}$. The metric used on $\ell^p$ is defined as $d(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|x(n)-y(n)|^p$ for all $x,y\in \ell^p$.

I have defined $F:\ell^{\infty}\to (\ell^{p})^*$ by $F(y)=f_y$ for all $y\in \ell^{\infty}$, where $f_y(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x(n)y(n)$. Clearly, $F$ is linear and it can be shown that $F$ is onto also. But how to show that $F$ is an isometry? I got stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it exercise 5, part (d) in chapter 3? In my edition, there's no mention of "isometric" there, and since Rudin doesn't treat the general duality theory to have a canonical topology on the dual of a topological vector space (whose dual separates points), in the context of the book it is undefined what "isometric" should mean in this situation.

Comment: Thus do I need to show that $F$ is linear isomorphism only?

Comment: Yes. In the second edition (it may have been different in the first) he writes "Show that $(\ell^p)^{\ast} = \ell^{\infty}$, in the same sense as in (a)". And in (a), he writes "…, in the following sense: There is a one-to-one correspondence $\Lambda \leftrightarrow y$ between $(\ell^p)^{\ast}$ and $\ell^q$, given by $\Lambda x = \sum x(n)y(n)$", nothing about isometry.

Comment: Unless you're interested in the question whether the strong topology $b(\ell^{\infty}, \ell^p)$ induced by $\ell^p$ on $\ell^{\infty}$ coincides with the norm topology on $\ell^{\infty}$, I'd be inclined to refund the bounty since it is still quite young, and was placed based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: Please don't refund the bounty as though initially I misunderstood the question, still I am also interested to know how the strong topology induced by $\ell^p$ on $\ell^{\infty}$ coincides with the norm topology on $\ell^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant $F\colon \ell ^{\infty}\rightarrow (\ell ^p)^*$, not just $\ell ^p$.  In any case, this is indeed an isomorphism in the category of topological vector spaces when $(\ell ^p)^*$ is equipped with the [strong polar topology](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Strong_topology_(polar_topology)) (the topology of uniform convergence on weakly-bounded subsets of $\ell ^p)$.

First note that a subset of $\ell ^p$ is weakly-bounded iff it is bounded in the $\ell ^1$ norm.  To see this, consider the following.  We already know that $(\ell ^p)^*\cong _{\mathbf{Vect}}\ell ^{\infty}$, and so $B\subseteq \ell ^p$ is weakly-bounded iff $y(B)\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is bounded for all $y\in \ell ^{\infty}$.  As $\ell ^p\subseteq \ell ^1$, we may regard $B$ as a subset of $\ell ^1$, and as we also know that $(\ell ^1)^*\cong \ell ^{\infty}$, we likewise have that $B\subseteq \ell ^1$ is weakly-bounded, and hence bounded by [Mackey's Theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700003579).  Thus, the strong polar topology on $(\ell ^p)^*$ is the topology of uniform convergence on $\ell ^1$-bounded subsets of $\ell ^p$.

You seem to already know how to check that $F$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.  To see that it is also a homeomorphism, first check that $F$ is continuous.  Let $\lambda \mapsto y^{\lambda}\in \ell ^{\infty}$ converge to $y\in \ell ^{\infty}$ and let $B\subseteq \ell ^p$ be $\ell ^1$-bounded.  Then, there is some constant $C$ such that $\| x\| _1\leq C$ for all $x\in B$.  Hence,
$$
\sum _{m\in \mathbb{N}}|(y_m^{\lambda}-y_m)x_m|\leq \| y^{\lambda}-y\| _{\infty}\| x\| _1\leq C\| y^{\lambda}-y\| _{\infty},
$$
and so $\lambda \mapsto y^{\lambda}$ converges to $y$ uniformly on $B$.

Conversely, suppose that $\lambda \mapsto y^{\lambda}$ converges to $y$ uniformly on every $\ell ^1$-bounded subset of $\ell ^p$.  Take $B:=\{ \mathbf{e}_m:m\in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\mathbf{e}_m\in \ell ^p$ is of course the sequence which is identically $0$ except for a $1$ at the $m^{\text{th}}$ index.  This is certainly $\ell ^1$-bounded, and hence for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is some $\lambda _0$ such that whenever $\lambda \geq \lambda _0$ it follows that
$$
\left| (y^{\lambda}-y)(\mathbf{e}_m)\right| =\left| y^{\lambda}_m-y_m\right| <\varepsilon .
$$
for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$.  That is, $\lambda \mapsto y^{\lambda}\in \ell ^{\infty}$ converges to $y\in \ell ^{\infty}$ with respect to the $\ell ^{\infty}$ norm.